# i have an javascript function that not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function filter_effect(effect_name){
    var tmp_img = document.createElement("IMG");
    tmp_img.src = get_cropped_image()
    tmp_img.style.display = "none"
    Caman(tmp_img, function (){
      this[effect_name](); 
          this.render(function () {
              change_picture(this.canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"))
      });
    });
}
```

this is my code and when I run this I get this error

> Uncaught TypeError: this[effect_name] is not a function

Can anyone help that what I should do to fix this?

Comment: What are you expecting `this` to refer to?

Comment: function filter-effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your function call and pass the `this`. Change this line, it would be solved:

```
Caman.call(this, tmp_img, function (){
   /* Your callback function body */
});
```

Here `this` means the `filter_effect` function. When you want to change the `this` object in function calls, you have to use .apply() or .call() to change it.

[Here is a reference for this post.](https://www.undefinednull.com/2014/06/26/explaining-call-and-apply-in-javascript-through-mr-dot-dave/)

Answer (score -1):

You have to clarify 'this' reference value, it must be refer to a javascript object which effect_name property of which be declared as function, use browser's debugger to have scrutiny over it's value

Comment: effect-name is my function parameter it shouldnt work?

Comment: this[effect_name] means you have a json with effective_name parameter: for example var v = { 'a': 'some_value', 'b': function(){ /*some expressions*/}} create an object which v['a'] is equal to 'some_value' and v['b'] is a reference to a function you defined. so effect-name is a string equals to 'this' property name

Comment: thnks for your guide